# Локализация Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Как русифицировать Eclipse Helios

Comment: Ответ есть на ютюбе: Вот ссылка:[Инструкция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1PzkSNsEqM) , [Линк на рускою документацию](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fspec-zone.ru%2FRU%2FJava%2FDocs%2F7%2Fapi%2F&redir_token=a0Sx1lXUVjQuRq5AskIqob4uUZR8MTUyNDIxMzk1M0AxNTI0MTI3NTUz&event=video_description&v=R1PzkSNsEqM) , [Линк на плагин Babel](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eclipse.org%2Fbabel%2Fdownloads.php&redir_token=a0Sx1lXUVjQuRq5AskIqob4uUZR8MTUyNDIxMzk1M0AxNTI0MTI3NTUz&event=video_description&v=R1PzkSNsEqM).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, это вопрос на [БитКод](http://user.hashcode.ru/), но раз у меня рядом есть ссылка: [пакеты для русского языка](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.9.0/helios/helios.php#ru) - выбирайте, какие нужны (в зависимости от набора плагинов).